# Is the limit of essential supremum equals to the origin function almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a locally integrable function on $\mathbb R^n$.
By [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#Statement), for almost every point $x$, one has
$$
\lim_{m(B) \to 0} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B f(y) dx = f(x).
$$
I want to know that, if we replace the $\frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B f(y) dx$ by $\operatorname{ess\,sup} f(y)$, is the statement remains true?

If it is true, is $\lim_{m(B) \to 0} \operatorname{ess\,sup} |f(y) - f(x)| = 0$ almost everywhere?

If not, what could we say about the limit of esssup function?

Comment: Well, no. For instance, consider $f$ the indicator of a dense open set $U$ with $m(\Bbb R\setminus U)>0$. Then, $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\operatorname{ess sup}\limits_{y\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus U$.

Comment: With the same idea you can tweak $f$ so that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ and $\operatorname{ess sup}_{y\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert=\infty$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\notin U$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, it is true that the limit of ess sup $f$ is not less than $f$ almost everywhere?

Comment: I don't understand. Do I evaluate "not" before or after "almost everywhere"?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, sorry for that. I mean $\lim \operatorname{ess\,sup} f \geq f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: That is actually true.